# Polymer 2.x typescript decorators example

Tags: typescript, polymer

This is where I am so for https://github.com/gertcuykens/decorators but I am strugeling how to go from the generated `decorators.js` to something I can use in my `index.html`? I guess I need to use webpack or something but I am not sure. When I try webpack it can't bundle my webcomponent into a working `bundle.js` for my `index.html`

I know its a bit of a brought question maybe but I am out of ideas how to make my `index.html` work?

Comment: after polymer 2 you can use internal decorator of polymer 2, check polymer summit 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have a working example alleluia, but not sure if `polymer imd` is better than the `requirejs` I am using.

https://github.com/gertcuykens/decorators